# Best practices with id's of many-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I have some doubts with the many-to-many tables id's (primary key). A many-to-many relationship is composed, according to the Laravel documentation, of two models and three tables. Each model has its corresponding table, and the intermediate table has as fields:

- Auto-incremental ID
- table1_id
- table2_id
- other_attributes ...

So far, all good. I have already used it a lot, accessing the fields with the helper 'pivot', and updating these with 'updateExistingPivot' and more.

The question I have is whether it is worth taking advantage of the ID of the intermediate table such as FK from attributes of other tables.

**EXAMPLE:**

In my application, I have these models:

- Machine
- Product
- Restriction

And these four tables:

- machines (id, name, ...) [Machine]
- products (id, name, ...) [Product]
- machine_products (id, machine_id[FK], product_id[FK], price) [without model]
- restrictions (id, machine_product_id[FK], day, begin_hour, end_hour) [Restriction]

Given a specific machine and a product, there are N restrictions.
One restriction belongs to one specific Machine and Product.

As you can see, I took advantage of the autoincremental ID (primary key of the intermediate table), to relate the restrictions. But in this way, working with Eloquent is a bit weird, like accessing a `Restriction` from a `Machine / Product` or vice versa, is not easy:

```
Restriction::where('machine_product_id', Machine::find(1)->products()->first()->pivot->id );
```

If I would get a `Product` or `Machine` from a given `Restriction`, I would have to find the 'machine_id' and 'product_id' from the row with the `machine_product_id` of the Restriction that I had.

I don't know if for practicality and functionality issues when working with Eloquent it would be better to do two many-to-many tables with `machine_id and product_id`, one with the `price (machine_products)` and the other with the `day, begin_hour, end_hour (restrictions)`. The first table would be 1 to 1 (machine_products) and the other 1 to N (restrictions). I mean:

- `machine_products` would have only one price, given a specific machine_id and a product_id.
- `restrictions` would have N rows of the set consisting of day, begin_hour, end_hour, given a specific machine_id and product_id.

Or it would be better if I make a model called `MachineProduct`?  I don't know...

Could you tell me or recommend the best way to solve this dilemma? Already modifying the tables, models, or whatever it takes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you were applying strict entity-relationship design to just your *Machine* and *Product* entities, your intermediate table would have just two columns.

```
 machine_id  INT PK  FK to machine.id
 product_it  INT PK  FK to product.id
```

This implements the `Machine  :: many-to-many :: Product` relationship.

This intermediate table would have a compound primary key. The uniqueness of the primary key would dictate that each Machine can have just one relationship with each Product. Create the relationship by inserting a row, and sever it by deleting that row.

But your real-world application has two more *things* in it, price and restriction.  It looks like your application dictates that prices have relationships both to Machines and Products.

So, we need another entity to describe your application clearly. Let's call it *Job*.  Each Job has a `price` attribute. It uses one machine to make one product. Therefore it has these relationships.

```
  Machine  :: many-to-one :: Job 
  Product  :: many-to-one :: Job
```

Your  `machines_products` table is therefore not a pure many:many intermediate table. Instead it is, and should be called, the Job table (or as you put it, the MachineProduct table).

Finally, you havew a Restriction entity with this relationship

```
  Job :: one-to-many :: Restriction
```

So, to make your Eloquent model of the real world clear, add that Job (MachineProduct) entity to your model.  The whole model looks like this. (It's interesting that the heart of it is the Job / MachineProduct entity.)

```
 +-------------+     +------------+     +---------------+   
 |             |    /|            |\    |               |   
 |   Product   |-----|     Job    |-----|     Machine   |   
 |             |    \|            |/    |               |   
 +-------------+     +------------+     +---------------+   
                            |                                
                            |                               
                           /|\
                     +-------------+                        
                     |             |                        
                     | Restriction |                        
                     |             |                        
                     +-------------+
```

**Pro tip**: It's best to figure out your entities and relationships clearly before you start creating tables.

**Pro tip**: Your database schema is probably easier to understand if you avoid column names like `machine.id`, and instead use `machine.machine_id`. That way you can say things like this in your queries

```
 FROM Job j JOIN Machine m ON j.machine_id = m.machine_id
```

instead of

```
 FROM Job j JOIN Machine m ON j.machine_id = m.id
```

and don't have to wonder, wait, what `id` is that, and don't risk doing this by mistake:

```
FROM Job j JOIN Product p ON j.machine_id = p.id  /* wrong */
```